# iOS app not close when crash happens

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

My app uses Fabric & Crashlytics in old version. And I changed to using Firebase to manage the report in new version.

And then my app start to not close app window when crash happens. (App view remains)

Could anyone give me some hint to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Did you try on real device?

Comment: I think your application doesn't crash, it might get freeze because of CPU/RAM overload due to your firebase methods might run in a long/forever loop or in the main thread.

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya Yes, this problem happens the same on real device.

Comment: @TonyTran I tested the firebase on a new empty project with same crash code. It works fine.

Comment: @TonyTran The situation is Fabric & Crashlytics works fine. Firebase freeze the view with the same crash code.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Can you provide a little bit more detail as to if you think Crashlytics is causing this? Thanks!